# kdb+ Q - return sum of integers contained in a list

Tags: kdb

I have a simple list of integers, how do i return the sum of all integer values contained within the list?

```
a:(5;10;15)
```

thanks

update: i had another list b:(2;4;6), and i joined both lists into one c:(a;b), now when i do sum c, it throws an error, any ideas?

solved: i used 'raze' when joining lists - `c:raze(a;b)` then sum c

Comment: Use `sum a` to get total sum

Comment: i joined two lists and the sum isnt working. not sure if i joined them correctly. I had a:(2;4;6) and b:(4;5;6), and i created c:(a;b), but now when i do sum c, it throws an error

Comment: `(sum/)c` or `sum raze c` should work

Comment: thank Cathal, how can the contents of the list be updated? for example multipy all elements by 5?

Comment: `c*5` should do it

Comment: @culldog88 Note that `(a;b)` is not concatenation - it is the creation of a list of lists. If you want to concatenate use `a,b`. Then a simple `sum` would work without the need to `raze`